# Detecting Exceptions in Parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to know if an exception has occured in a Parent class method while overriding the same method in the child class ?

```
class Customer:
       def withdraw(self, amount):
             if self.__account_balance < self.get_min_balance:
                     raise LimitException()


class PrivCustomer(Customer):
       def withdraw(self, amount):
             """ here how do I detect if an exception has occurred in the withdraw method of Customer class ?""""
```

Comment: Have you tried using `try`? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: @HåkenLid I think I got it...thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your `PrivCustomer.withdraw` method will *replace* the `Customer.withdraw` method for `PrivCustomer` objects.  To call `Customer.withdraw`, you have to use `super().withdraw` to get the inherited method.  That method call will be where `LimitException` is raised

```
class PrivCustomer(Customer):
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        try:
            super().withdraw(amount)
        except LimitException:
            ...
```